# How do I explain an employment gap resulting from not having an experience letter?

Tags: resume, india, relieving-letter

I got a job after my Masters, and worked there for 10 months. I had some issues with my supervisor so I left the place without giving proper notice. Naturally, I did not get the Experience Letter from the company. 
After 11 months, I got another job at a small firm where 10 people worked. They did not insist on the prior Experience Letter. I worked there for 10 months and then got another job. They only asked for the latest Experience Letter which I did have.

However, I think lately the background checks have become stricter, and I recently lost an amazing job opportunity due to not being able to produce the Experience Letter from my first job.

Obviously, I cannot show the first job on my resume since background check requires the relevant Experience Letter. As a result, I now have to show nearly 2 years gap after my Masters (10 months of employment at the first company followed by 11 months of unemployment).

I have nearly 4 years of continuous work experience. What explanation could I give for the gap of 2 years?

Comment: Glad to meet you ... did you have a question?

Comment: yes i my problem is i cant seem to figure out what should i explain in an interview about what i did 2 years after my masters.since i dont have experience letter from first job i did for 10 months then i was unemployed for 11 months thats nearly 2 years gap.Its quite frustrating since i want to change the job but 2 years gap right at the start of my resume leaves a big hole and recruiters wont miss it

Comment: You tell them that you were employed for 10 months but don't have an experience letter, and then you were unemployed for 11 months. By the way, if you did not have another job offer lined up, why did you quit the first job without proper notice?

Comment: ok that was my fault.i didnt know the importance of experience letter i had bad relations with my supervisor and just walked out of there.Since then though i have learnt my lesson and have got solid track record at current organization.I told this to another company where i got pretty amazing opportunity they rescinded their offer immediately.So i am completely clueless now

Comment: I have edited the question to include those details you mentioned in the above comment.

Comment: Let me guess, are you from India?

Comment: Which country is this?

Comment: What is an "experience letter"?

Comment: Where are you located?

Comment: The issues were that the department i was assigned was basically only data entry assignments.I repeatedly asked my manager to change the department which will be more challenging and will fit to my profile.Another thing is rotational work timings weekly.I would go to work 4:30 am one week an 8:30 pm next week.So 6 am then 10 pm start of work timings every alternate week which was killer for my health.So out of frustration i quit that job.Joe i already tried explaining truth the a job offer 5 months ago.They rescinded their offer as i couldnt produce the experience letter.I am located in India.

Answer (score 3):

> Obviously, I cannot show the first job on my resume since background check requires the relevant Experience Letter
>   [..]
>   What explanation could I give for the gap of 2 years?

I don't think there is a good explanation for the gap, apart from the truth.

If you leave a gap in a CV, the first thing any decent HR person / interviewer will do is ask about it (if they do not just dismiss your application). They will ask because any gap looks like you are trying to hide something, and that might be something relevant for the job (maybe a time in prison).

So I agree with  Joe Strazzere's assesment: Tell the truth. Maybe something like:

> January-October 2012: data entry specialist, XY corp. Employer declined to provide experience letter.

That is honest, without going into too much detail, and without badmouthing your former employer (which is important).

Of course, a new employer may still decide that they absolutely, positively *must* have an experience letter. Then there's nothing you can do. However, that way at least you do not have a gap, and if your CV passes the first round, you can explain in the interview exactly what happened.

Answer (score 1):

Try to get an experience letter from the HR department of the company instead of from the manager. The HR department might be willing to give you an experience letter showing the information they have about you such as the start and end dates, job title etc. Often this is sufficient for a new employer.